# Undefined method error while executing Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is my work_spec.rb file looks like.
I am getting the **by_letter** undefined method error while running that code..

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

describe Work do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:work).should be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a last_name" do
     FactoryGirl.build((:work), last_name: nil).should be_valid
  end

  it "returns a sorted array of result that match" do
    smith = FactoryGirl.create((:work), last_name: "smith")
    jones = FactoryGirl.create((:work), last_name: "jones")
    johnson = FactoryGirl.create((:work), last_name: "johnson")

    Work.by_letter("j").should == [johnson, jones]
  end
end


Error receved while running
     Work returns a sorted array of result that match
     Failure/Error: Work.by_letter("j").should == [johnson, jones]
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method `by_letter' for #<Class:0x0000000429a708>
     # ./spec/models/work_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: And you state that this message is not correct? You do have a static method `def self.by_letter` in your class `Work`?

Comment: Could you show your `Work` class and your `Work` factory please?

Comment: `FactoryGirl.define do`
  `factory :work do |f|`
    `f.first_name "j"`
    `f.last_name "ja"`
  `end`
`end`

Comment: you haven't defined the scope - that's why it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is failing is because you have not defined the method `by_letter` in the `Work` class.